# Evaluate current PowerShell session version from C# class during script module import

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-core

First, some background on what I'm trying to do. I am writing a PowerShell script module that needs to set some variables and run some code when the module is imported. What ultimately needs to happen is dependent on the version of PowerShell the module is being imported into. For example, this needs to support 5.1 and later, but `Invoke-RestMethod` does not support the
`-SkipCertificateCheck` parameter until PowerShell 6, meaning I need to check the version, create a [dummy ICertificatePolicy](https://gist.github.com/bender-the-greatest/26e758cd1ad7b8ae87c688301cac697e) that essentially always returns `true` when validating, and store that in a global place somewhere I can reference it and set that policy if the user dictates they want to skip security checks when calling certain cmdlets. I have the following code so far:

```
Add-Type @"
  using System.Management.Automation;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

  namespace MyModuleNamespace {
    public struct State {
      public static ICertificatePolicy SystemCertificatePolicy;
      public static ICertificatePolicy SkipSSLCheckPolicy;
    }

    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
      public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  namespace MyModuleNamespace.SubNamespace {
    public class ModuleAssemblyInitializer : IModuleAssemblyInitializer {
      public void OnImport() {
        // pseudocode of what I'm struggling to define in C#
        if( CurrentPSSession.PSVersion.Major -lt 6 ) {
          MyModuleNamespace.State.SystemCertificatePolicy = ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy;
          MyModuleNamespace.State.SkipSSLCheckPolicy = new MyModuleNamespace.TrustAllCertsPolicy();
        }
        // end pseudocode
      }
    }
  }
"@
```

However... I am struggling to evaluate information from the current PowerShell session, such as evaluating `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`. I know how to check which versions of PowerShell are installed, but I need to be able to evaluate the currently running version of PowerShell which this class is added to. Additionally, I don't want the *entire* module to be written in C# even though this is technically an option. Others on my team will be expected to maintain the module and while they know PowerShell well, C# is outside of their skillset.

If there is a PowerShell-native way to handle the case of running code when the module is imported, I'm all ears. This is my first PowerShell module and wouldn't be surprised if I'm approaching this problem with the wrong solution.

Comment: Of the top of my head, calling `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` in `OnImport()` should return you the importing `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly

Comment: Wouldn't the version information only return information about the .NET assemby version, not the version of PowerShell?

Comment: `System.Management.Automation.dll` _is_ PowerShell

Comment: Yes, but if I inspect the version on that the version still matches the version of .NET PowerShell is running under, unless I'm missing something. For example, if I run `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetCallingAssembly()` from my PS session, it still only shows `v4.0.30319`, and nothing about the PowerShell version I'm running. I get the same version on Windows' at least whether I run that through `powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe`.

Comment: A quick test from PowerShell 7 on a Linux box also shows the same assembly version. So doesn't seem this will work. It does look like the assembly location is under a `PowerShell/7` specific path on Windows, but Linux doesn't have a specific version in the path at least using the `snap` package for PowerShell. This *would* work for detecting between Windows PS and PS Core in my situation, but if I ever needed to tell between PS 6 and 7 it wouldn't be effective. I did find a solution that works for me though and will be posting it as an answer shortly.

Comment: That's because the PowerShell statement `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetCallingAssembly()` is transformed into a LINQ Expression and executed directly by the DLR - your `IModuleAssemblyInitializer.OnImport()` implementation will be called from the session state initializer in S.M.A. Seriously, give it a try

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what I need to give a try here. I'm not sure what SMA is if that's the secret sauce.

Comment: Sorry, `S.M.A` == `System.Management.Automation`. What I'm suggesting you try is: call `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` inside `OnImport()`, compile to a dll, import said dll with `Import-Module` and you'll find that the calling assembly is `System.Management.Automation`

Comment: Okay, but how can I use that to determine the current PowerShell version? All I can see from inspecting the assembly is the .NET version information, not the PowerShell version information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In general, I'd strongly suggest **not doing this at all**. Blindly skipping certificate trust validation is a bad idea.*

---

As I was (poorly) trying to explain in the comments, if you resolve the calling assembly (ie. `System.Management.Automation.dll`), you might be able to use that to discover version information in the initializer using reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CrossVersionModule
{
    public class ModuleAssemblyInitializer : IModuleAssemblyInitializer
    {
        public void OnImport()
        {
            // obtain reference to calling assembly
            var caller = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

            // locate the PSVersionInfo type
            var psversionType = caller.GetType("System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo");
            if (null != psversionType)
            {
                // locate the PSVersion property
                PropertyInfo versionProp = psversionType.GetProperty("PSVersion");
                if (null == versionProp) {
                    // In .NET framework (ie. Windows PowerShell 5.1) we have to explicitly pass binding flags for non-public members
                    versionProp = psversionType.GetProperty("PSVersion", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
                }

                // Invoke the getter to get the value
                var getter = versionProp.GetGetMethod(true);
                var version = getter.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
                Console.WriteLine(version); // here's where you'd do your version check
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I compile the above against [PowerShell Standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library), I get the correct PowerShell versions when importing in 5.1 and 7 respectively

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense, thank you. I also found another way that works too making use of the calling/entry assembly (either works), I'll post it as an answer as well.

Comment: Also, ignoring cert errors is just one case of differences between Windows PS/PS Core. This is intended to be used during development scenarios, we don't need to ignore SSL errors in deployed environments.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Cool, just had to slap a disclaimer on it for posterity :) In general I'd be inclined to defer all version checks until runtime (fetch the `$PSVersionTable` variable via `PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable` inside a cmdlet for example, or add a `ScriptsToProcess` entry with a script that copies the version to module scope for future use)

Comment: `SessionState.PSVariable`... thanks for that @MathiasR.Jessen!

Answer (score 0):

I found a few ways to be able to determine the .NET version in addition to Mathias' [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63837020/584676).

One was to expand an expressions in the string, and add the following code to my `struct State` to insert the values from `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` into the C# code, which would then be readable elsewhere in the module code:

```
public struct State {
  public static ICertificatePolicy SystemCertificatePolicy = ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy;
  public static ICertificatePolicy SkipSSLCheckPolicy;
  
  // Lines below were added
  public readonly static System.Version PSVersion;

  static State() {
    PSVersion = new Version(
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major),
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor),
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Build),
      $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Revision)
    );
  }
}
```

The other way that worked was to check the value of the calling assembly's product attribute, which can return one of a few things for `AssemblyProductAttribute` on the calling assembly:

- If calling from PowerShell directly

  - `Microsoft® .NET Framework` if using Windows PowerShell
  - `Microsoft® .NET Core` if using PowerShell Core
- If calling from C# compiled within a PowerShell script using `Add-Type`

  - `Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System` if on .NET Framework
  - `PowerShell` if using .NET Core
- Not sure what this returns from a properly compiled C# project when compiled against the .NET Core SDK

In my case I can check if the attribute equals `PowerShell` to see if this is .NET Core:

```
// New using directives
using System;
using System.Reflection;

// Check if .NET Core
AssemblyProductAttribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute)) as AssemblyProductAttribute;
if(attribute.Product == "PowerShell")) {
  // do .NET Core things
}
```

Seems the third method has some issues at runtime and I've removed it from this answer until I can figure out what is happening.